# Convert standard rails / ruby time to American format - dates getting mixed up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime, datepicker

I'm trying to convert the YYYY-MM-DD format in my forms and show views to MM/DD/YYYY - which is a pretty standard American date format. Not sure how to go about this - I thought that calling `.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")` on the date instance in /show would do the trick. Very confused - can't find documentation that explains how to convert dates that actually makes sense. I'm following this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised

If it helps, I'm using the jQuery datepicker and have this coffeescript:

```
jQuery ->
  $('input.datepicker').datepicker()
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
    weekStart: 0
    autoclose: true
```

_form

```
   <%= f.label :due %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :due, { :class => 'datepicker' } %>
```

The above enters the date with the MM/DD/YYYY format into the form, but it is saved as YYYY-MM-DD

--- UPDATE/SOLUTION FOUND ---

Turns out I was on the right track and not actually crazy. Part of my issue was that I was having a nil object problem which was remedied by calling `.try` in my views which will only run the method if not nil.

```
.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Also - I installed the following gem: `gem 'american_date'` which automagically parses the dates. Works great in show views, but still getting YYYY-MM-DD in form views (edit view only).

Comment: Why do you care how it's saved if it's displayed right?

Comment: I don't want to confuse my users, as they expect standard American formatting for dates.

Comment: I know. The point is, as long as it is *displayed* in the American format, who cares how it's stored?

Comment: True, I don't care how its stored. I just realized I was having a nil object prolem which was remedied with .try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%Y")

Comment: If you solved your problem add the answer below as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 4):

We have to solve three tasks when working with dates in RoR. I found these solutions as the most easiest for me:

### 1.How to display the date correctly.

Install **I18n** gem and check date format in your config\locales\en.yml. Then use **I18n.l()** (or just l) form helper to localize dates in your html.erb files.

```
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%m/%d/%y"
```

### 2.How to modify date in convenient way for user.

Use jQuery datepicker (or bootstrap datepicker etc.) and set date format in jQuery widget options in accordance to en.yml format.

### 3.How to convert date from localized (view) format to activerecord attribute.

Install **Delocalize** gem and add :input sub-section into date: section of en.yml file.

```
input:
  formats:
    - :default
```

Now your date will be automatically converted from localized format (mm/dd/yy) into database format (yyyy-mm-dd) when you assign it.

Answer (score 3):

I have had to use the `altField` and `altFormat` options to get this to work as described:

```
$('input.datepicker').datepicker({
   dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", 
   altField: alt_field, 
   altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
```

This requires having a hidden field `alt_field` that actually holds your date in the standard db format.

Comment: PinnyM, This looks like a potential solution. I don't know much about doing a hidden 'alt_field' - Any recommended reading? Do I need to add this to my model or just form?

Comment: You add it to your form - see [the docs](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field) for an example.

Comment: I've added the following to my form (after f.label & f.text_field). Datepicker and show works, but still not saving the date correctly.
--------

   <%= f.hidden_field :due, { :class => 'alternative' } %>

Comment: The text_field needs to have a different name - one that doesn't collide with the hidden field.  You'll need to initialize the text_field value (formatted for display) based on the model object, and use the hidden field to update your model object.  And replace `alt_field` with a selector for your hidden field - `'#model_name_due'`.  If it still doesn't work - please post the complete html you are using.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, PinnyM. I ended up finding a gem that just made American dates simple: gem 'american_date'

Answer (score 0):

include the below gem, it will automatically save the american date into db format.

```
gem 'american_date'
```